# Server time wait differs by the factor 10 on same server

Tags: load-time

I have two sites running on the same server. They use the same configuration (PHP version, WordPress settings, HTTPS, .htaccess rules etc.) While one site shows in Pingdom a wait time for images around 30 ms, the other shows a wait time 10 times higher for a similar sized JPG. Both sites are quite fast, but the first one is considerably faster. I have  absolutely no clue what might cause this huge difference. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! Have you tested these sites several times during different times? It could simply be an anomaly. Cheers!!

Comment: Yes, I have tested both sites several times. The waiting time is more or less the same. Thank you!

Comment: What if you test twice in a row?  Is the time faster for the second test?  If so that could indicate that faster speeds are caused by the web server caching images in memory.

Comment: No, the wait time doesn't change very much.